# Server, that waits for two clients in a "while"

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I need to make a server that waits two clients to connect, and puts them in other function in other thread. Server must transport data from A to B clients. If client A connects, it starts to wait for client B, but I'm stuck on checking that A is online, and if not, to wait for A again.

I already have that code

```
while (true) {
    sockaddr_in addr;
    int* addrlen = new int(sizeof(addr));
    SOCKET a = accept(server, (sockaddr*) &addr, addrlen);
    SOCKET b;
    sockaddr_in bddr;
    thread *bl = new thread([&]{b = accept(server, (sockaddr*) &bddr, addrlen);});
}
```

Comment: check the link is up or not if not then start accepting again

Comment: Why do you do the second accept in it's own thread?

Comment: Because I thought, that I can accept on other thread and check the A on main thread. If A is interrupted, I need to stop the B thread and break the while

Comment: Don't do the accept in another thread. Leave it in the original thread. Pass A to the second thread so it can start monitoring A's status and terminate itself if A disconnects, then pass B to the second thread when B becomes available. The accept loop can also monitor the status of the second thread and stop waiting for B if the thread terminates before B connects.